# VS Team Services Use VNext(VS '15') MSBuild

Tags: msbuild, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

So I am using the Hosted agent to run builds. We need to compile our site which uses typescript 2.0. In the build configuration when we switch our Visual Studio Version to VS '15' (preview) the following happens during the build.

[image]

Is there some sort of configuration I have to do to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Visual Studio 15 is not available on Hosted agent, also there isn’t typescript 2.0 installed on hosted agent.

You can add TypeScript MSBuild task package (2.0.6) to your project and using it to compile typescript files.

1. Install [Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild/) package
2. Edit your project file (.csproj):

1:

```
<Import Project="..\packages\Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild.2.0.6\build\Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild.props" Condition="Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild.2.0.3\build\Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild.props')" />
  <!--<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.Default.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.Default.props')" />-->
```

2:

```
<!--<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets')" />-->
<Import Project="..\packages\Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild.2.0.6\build\Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild.targets" Condition="Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild.2.0.6\build\Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild.targets')" />
```